# how can i run a c++ file in turbo c in windows 7

Tags: c++, turbo-c++, bgi

hi my dear friends :

i am asp.net web developer and never work with c++
i have a little project from my sister that i want to test it for her about car graphic like below :
[that code](http://www.cplusplus.happycodings.com/Computer_Graphics/code28.html)

```
Animated 3D Car in Turbo C++ 3.0
It consist of Lights effect, Sound Effect.
Press 'L' for Lights effect and 'H' for Horn.

#include<graphics.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<dos.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<process.h>

void main()
{
   int gd=DETECT,gm;
   initgraph(&gd,&gm,"c:\tc\bgi");
int c=12;
setbkcolor(0);
//setlinestyle(0,1,2);
int t;
while(1)
{
settextstyle(2,0,5);
outtextxy(100,10,"Press L,H ,T,P");
outtextxy(100,30,"Press 1 for Quit");
as:
setcolor(13);
ellipse(380,127,20,152,130,35);
//////////////////////////////rear//////////////////////////

line(490,109,560,142);
line(560,142,569,142);
line(569,142,582,102);
line(582,102,620,92);
line(593,132,617,125);

line(617,124,627,96);
line(620,92,628,97);

line(472,86,602,96);
line(501,113,575,121);
line(443,77,475,80);

line(443,77,432,93);
line(475,80,472,85);
//setcolor(4);
   line(593,132,593,137);
   line(593,137,600,141);
   line(600,141,600,185);
   line(600,185,608,192);
   line(608,192,608,234);
   line(608,234,586,253);
    line(586,253,577,248);

/////////////////////////           mirror
   line(263,112,363,127);
      line(193,160,263,112);
   line(193,160,220,170);
      line(220,170,280,180);
      line(280,180,320,185);
      line(320,185,363,127);
////////////////////////////////sidemirror
line(340,194,460,169);
 line(460,169,519,152);

ellipse(512,144,300,30,10,10);
ellipse(467,143,28,100,50,30);
line(510,128,521,138);
line(435,116,440,171);

//   setcolor(4);           
////////////////////////////////////////cont//
   line(339,194,372,144);
//    line(372,140,386,128);
ellipse(454,208,87,123,128,95);
line(372,144,384,128);
   int b,x,y;
////////////////////////lower
line(365,298,524,264);
line(365,298,330,310);
line(330,310,323,310);


///////////////////////////////bumper
ellipse(162,221,135,190,90,40);
line(96,193,140,174);
line(140,174,160,168);
line(160,168,192,161);

//////////////////////front
ellipse(75,246,95,190,18,18);
line(57,251,57,286);
//setcolor(4);
ellipse(181,178,232,263,200,137);
ellipse(195,180,256,286,200,137);


ellipse(191,171,228,247,200,100);
ellipse(231,198,234,275,200,80);

//setcolor(9);
//ellipse(195,170,256,286,200,137);
//setcolor(12);

ellipse(196,167,228,246,200,90);
ellipse(231,184,234,276,200,80);


ellipse(191,200,228,246,200,90);
ellipse(228,218,234,276,200,80);

ellipse(258,268,180,220,200,40);
ellipse(178,296,244,355,16,10);

ellipse(238,249,227,250,200,60);


/////////////wheel1
ellipse(302,281,320,77,26,45);
ellipse(290,277,65,162,40,45);
ellipse(278,288,144,212,31,45);

/////////////wheel2
//setcolor(5);
ellipse(302+260,229,328,87,26,45);
ellipse(290+280-7,277-50+2,90,162,40,45);
ellipse(278+270,288-50,144,215,27,45);
 b=0;
int v=0;

/////////
ellipse(302+250+v,227+b,295,90,29,41);
ellipse(302+234+v,231+b,245,306,50,40);
//setlinestyle(3,0,3);
ellipse(302+248+v,229+b,0,360,21,30);

ellipse(302+247+v,229+b,0,360,8,10);
setfillstyle(6,11);
//floodfill(302+248+v,230+b,13);
//line(546,201,546,257);
//line(554,201,554,257);
//setcolor(4);

line(546+v,201+b,546+v,220+b);
line(551+v,201+b-2,551+v,220+b);

line(546+v,238+b,546+v,257+b);
line(551+v,238+b+2,551+v,257+b+2);


line(530+v,225+b,541+v,225+b);
line(530+v,230+b,541+v,230);

line(557+v,225+b,570+v,225+b);
line(557+v,230+b,570+v,230+b);



line(563+v,206+b,552+v,222+b);
line(534+v,246+b,543+v,232+b);

line(566+v,210+b,556+v,223+b);
line(536+v,250+b,544+v,238+b);

line(536+v,207+b,546+v,222+b);
line(532+v,213+b,542+v,224+b);

line(556+v,235+b,566+v,247+b);
line(551+v,237+b,563+v,253+b);



////////////////////////////////////////////////////
v=-260;
b=56;
ellipse(302+233+v,221+b,260,60,49,51);
//ellipse(302+234+v,231+b,245,306,50,40);
//setlinestyle(3,0,3);
ellipse(302+243+v,224+b,0,360,28,35);
//  line(249,328,269,328);
ellipse(300+245+v,223+b,0,360,10,12);

ellipse(285+249+v,239+b,210,260,30,33);
//floodfill(285+258+v,230+b,12);
b=45;
v=v-4;
line(546+v,201+b,546+v,220+b+2);
line(551+v,201+b,551+v,220+b+2);
b=b+8;
line(546+v,238+b,546+v,257+b+4);
line(551+v,238+b,551+v,257+b+4);
v=v-2;
line(530+v-6,225+b,541+v,225+b);
line(530+v-6,230+b,541+v,230+b);
v=v+5;
line(557+v,225+b,570+v+3,225+b);
line(557+v-1,230+b,570+v+3,230+b);


b=b-5;
v=v-5;
line(565+v+3,206+b,552+v+4,222+b-2);
b=b+15;

line(534+v,246+b,543+v+3,232+b-5);
b=b-10;
line(566+v+7,210+b-5,556+v+4,220+b);
line(536+v-5,250+b,544+v-2,238+b-4);


line(536+v,207+b-8,545+v,222+b-5);
line(531+v,212+b-8,542+v,224+b-2);

line(556+v,235+b,566+v+3,247+b+5);
line(551+v,237+b,563+v+2,253+b+3);

///////////////////lights
ellipse(199,250,144,345,18,8);
line(185,245,206,230);
//setcolor(4);
ellipse(223,234,340,110,8,5);
line(230,237,217,252);
line(206,230,220,229);
//setfillstyle(1,4);

//floodfill(200,240,12);

/////////////////////////////////////
line(90,223,152,236);
line(152,236,137,254);
line(90,223,90,242);

//setfillstyle(10,9);
//floodfill(91,230,14);
ellipse(240,270,104,136,100,60);
ellipse(185,237,120,160,100,60);
ellipse(80,221,357,134,10,10);

line(152,236,168,228);
///////////////////////////////////////////////
line(435,116,440,171);
//////////////////////////////////////////hp
//line(134,185,220,210);
line(134,185,196,160);
line(214,212,318,185);
/////////////////////////////////////////////////light

//setcolor(14);
ellipse(166,247,99,330,8,8);
ellipse(171,243,310,129,7,7);
putpixel(174,250,13);
putpixel(173,251,13);
putpixel(164,239,13);
putpixel(165,238,13);

/////////////////////////////////////////road/////////////////////
setcolor(13);
line(1,430,639,300);
line(1,445,639,315);

line(1,210,93,194);
line(1,195,194,158);

//line(1,170,639,71);
//line(1,170,229,135);
line(520,90,639,71);
line(478,86,639,56);

   int c=0;

   line(10,194+c,10,208+c);
line(40,189+c,40,204+c);
line(70,183+c,70,198+c);
line(100,176+c,100,190+c);
line(130,170+c,130,177+c);
line(160,166+c,160,168+c);
line(190,160+c,190,161+c);

 line(190+330,78+c,190+330,89+c);

line(190+360,72+c,190+360,85+c);
line(190+390,67+c,190+390,81+c);
line(190+420,62+c,190+420,76+c);
line(190+449,57+c,190+449,71+c);



   c=236;

line(10,192+c,10,208+c);
line(40,189+c-2,40,204+c-3);
line(70,183+c-3,70,198+c-3);
line(100,176+c-2,100,190+c-2);
line(130,170+c-2,130,177+c+5);
line(160,166+c-3,160,168+c+8);
line(190,160+c-4,190,161+c+9);

line(190+30,156+c-5,190+30,170+c-5);


line(190+30+30,156+c-12,190+30+30,170+c-12);

line(190+90,156+c-18,190+90,170+c-17);

line(190+120,156+c-25,190+120,170+c-25);

line(190+150,156+c-30,190+150,170+c-30);

line(190+180,156+c-37,190+180,170+c-36);


line(190+210,156+c-42,190+210,170+c-42);


line(190+240,156+c-48,190+240,170+c-48);


line(190+270,156+c-55,190+270,170+c-54);


line(190+300,156+c-61,190+300,170+c-61);



 line(190+330,78+c+10,190+330,89+c+13);

line(190+360,72+c+11,190+360,85+c+13);
line(190+390,67+c+10,190+390,81+c+10);
line(190+420,62+c+8,190+420,76+c+10);
line(190+449,57+c+8,190+449,71+c+8);




/////////////////road

setcolor(12);          /////////////////////////////1

line(1,310,25,306);
line(6,318,30,315);
line(1,310,6,318);
line(25,306,30,314);
int k,m;
k=13*45+19;
m=16*(-8);
                            //2
setcolor(12);

line(605,310-128,629,306-128);
line(610,318-128,634,315-128);
line(605,310-128,610,318-128);
line(629,306-128,634,314-128);

setcolor(12);    //////////////////////////////////3
k=45;
m=-8;
line(46,302,70,298);
line(51,310,75,307);
line(46,302,51,310);
line(70,298,75,306);


setfillstyle(1,0);
floodfill(64,303,12);

setfillstyle(1,14);
floodfill(14,314,12);
floodfill(617,183,12);

setfillstyle(1,0);
floodfill(14,314,12);
floodfill(617,183,12);

setfillstyle(1,14);
floodfill(64,303,12);

t=getch();
if(t=='1')
exit(0);
if(t=='h')
{
sound(710);
delay(500);
nosound();
//break;
}
if(t=='t')
{
while(!kbhit())  {
setfillstyle(1,0);
floodfill(536,213,13);
floodfill(563,213,13);
floodfill(561,244,13);
floodfill(538,244,13);
floodfill(274,295,13);
floodfill(294,295,13);
floodfill(274,265,13);
floodfill(294,265,13);
floodfill(548,250,13);
floodfill(548,214,13);
floodfill(533,228,13);
floodfill(563,228,13);
floodfill(262,281,13);
floodfill(308,281,13);
floodfill(284,251,13);
floodfill(284,295,13);

setfillstyle(1,random(12));

floodfill(200,250,13);
delay(10);
//setfillstyle(1,11);

 floodfill(170,250,13);
 floodfill(80,230,13);


 }

setfillstyle(1,0);

floodfill(200,250,13);
delay(10);
//setfillstyle(1,11);

 floodfill(170,250,13);
 floodfill(80,230,13);

    }


if(t=='l')
{
while(!kbhit())
{

delay(120);
setfillstyle(6,0);         //////////////////////////ty
floodfill(536,213,13);
floodfill(563,213,13);
floodfill(561,244,13);
floodfill(538,244,13);
floodfill(274,295,13);
floodfill(294,295,13);
floodfill(274,265,13);
floodfill(294,265,13);

setfillstyle(1,0);
floodfill(64,303,12);

///////////////////////////////////road

setfillstyle(9,0);       /////////////////////color
floodfill(81-40+5,419+7,13);
floodfill(151-40,409+7,13);
floodfill(211-40,397+7,13);
floodfill(271-40,380+7,13);
floodfill(331-40,368+7,13);
floodfill(396-40,355+7,13);
floodfill(450-40,345+7,13);
floodfill(510-40,335+7,13);
floodfill(570-40,325+7,13);
floodfill(630-40,312+7,13);


//////////////////////
floodfill(50,197,13);
floodfill(110,177,13);
floodfill(166,165,13);
floodfill(527,86,13);
floodfill(587,71,13);




setfillstyle(6,14); //////////////////////////ty
floodfill(548,250,13);
floodfill(548,214,13);
floodfill(533,228,13);
floodfill(563,228,13);
floodfill(262,281,13);
floodfill(308,281,13);
floodfill(284,251,13);
floodfill(284,295,13);
////////////////////////////////////////road

setfillstyle(9,10);///////////////////////////////////color
floodfill(19,429,13);
floodfill(81,419,13);
floodfill(151,409,13);
floodfill(211,397,13);
floodfill(271,380,13);
floodfill(331,368,13);
floodfill(396,355,13);
floodfill(450,345,13);
floodfill(510,335,13);
floodfill(570,325,13);
floodfill(630,312,13);
//////////////////////////////////////
floodfill(20,197,13);
floodfill(80,187,13);
floodfill(133,174,13);
floodfill(517,86,13);
floodfill(557,81,13);
floodfill(627,70,13);

setfillstyle(1,14);
floodfill(14,314,12);
floodfill(617,183,12);

///////////////////////////////////////
setfillstyle(10,4);
floodfill(302+248,230,13);
floodfill(302+248+v,230+b,13);
///light
setfillstyle(6,11);                             ///////////

floodfill(200,250,13);

floodfill(170,250,13);
 floodfill(80,230,13);

delay(120);

setfillstyle(6,0);/////////////////////ty
floodfill(548,250,13);
floodfill(548,214,13);
floodfill(533,228,13);
floodfill(563,228,13);
floodfill(262,281,13);
floodfill(308,281,13);
floodfill(284,251,13);
floodfill(284,295,13);
/////////////////////////////////////road
setfillstyle(9,0);      ///////////////color

floodfill(19,429,13);
floodfill(81,419,13);
floodfill(151,409,13);
floodfill(211,397,13);
floodfill(271,380,13);
floodfill(331,368,13);
floodfill(396,355,13);
floodfill(450,345,13);
floodfill(510,335,13);
floodfill(570,325,13);
floodfill(630,312,13);
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
floodfill(20,197,13);
floodfill(80,187,13);
floodfill(133,174,13);
floodfill(517,86,13);
floodfill(557,81,13);
floodfill(627,70,13);
/////////////////////////////
setfillstyle(1,0);
floodfill(14,314,12);
floodfill(617,183,12);

setfillstyle(6,10);            /////////////ty

floodfill(536,213,13);
floodfill(563,213,13);
floodfill(561,244,13);
floodfill(538,244,13);
floodfill(274,295,13);
floodfill(294,295,13);
floodfill(274,265,13);
floodfill(294,265,13);
////////////////////////////////////////////////road
setfillstyle(9,14);/////////////////////////////////////////color
floodfill(81-40+5,419+7,13);
floodfill(151-40,409+7,13);
floodfill(211-40,397+7,13);
floodfill(271-40,380+7,13);
floodfill(331-40,368+7,13);
floodfill(396-40,355+7,13);
floodfill(450-40,345+7,13);
floodfill(510-40,335+7,13);
floodfill(570-40,325+7,13);
floodfill(630-40,312+7,13);
/////////////////////////////////////////

floodfill(50,197,13);
floodfill(110,177,13);
floodfill(166,165,13);
floodfill(527,86,13);
floodfill(587,71,13);
setfillstyle(1,14);
floodfill(64,303,12);

setfillstyle(9,4);
floodfill(302+248,230,13);
floodfill(302+248+v,230+b,13);

delay(20);
setfillstyle(1,14);

floodfill(200,250,13);

floodfill(170,250,13);
 floodfill(80,230,13);

 delay(20);
setfillstyle(1,0);

floodfill(200,250,13);

floodfill(170,250,13);
 floodfill(80,230,13);




}          }




if(t=='p')
{
int n=0;
while(!kbhit())
{
if(n<=60)
n++;
setcolor(0);
rectangle(1+1,-10,90-1,-12+n);
delay(14);

setcolor(9);
rectangle(1,-10,90,-10+n);
if(n==60)
{

outtextxy(10,10,"L-LIGHTS");
outtextxy(10,20,"H-HORN");
//outtextxy(10,30,"T-AllOY");
 delay(400);
 }


}
setcolor(0);
rectangle(1,-10,90,-10+n);
rectangle(1,-10,90,-11+n);
outtextxy(10,10,"L-LIGHTS");
outtextxy(10,20,"H-HORN");
//outtextxy(10,30,"T-AllOY");

}

}



circle(300,100,3);

nosound();

getch();
}
```

we both are new in turbo c++
**we should use turbo c dos**
**also i am using windows 7 ultimate**

i downloded turbo c++ dos from internet
but when i run the upper code in it i have some errors ...
i think there is something wrong about me , not that project
so my Questions are :

1-where is the best place for download latest ver turbo c++ -> dos  //i know this is old but we should use it?
2-is there any problem about that project?
3-is that turbo c++ work on windows 7 ultimate?
4-how can i full screen turbo c++ in windows 7?

really really thanks for attention to my funny questions

Comment: It's always good to include what you mean by 'some errors'...

Comment: Why would you want to? Forget Turbo C, and get CodeBlocks at http://codeblocks.org

Comment: I believe you will struggle due to the way graphics was handled back then. You may do better to load a virtual machine with MS DOS to run it in.

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/227739/foxpro-2-6-dos-on-windows-7-64-bit and probably some other superuser questions

Comment: thanks for comments / but she should learn turbo c++ and working with it / i do n't know what is wrong with her teacher

Comment: Not a single customs function, function with 5+ arg, working only on very old hardware (welcome back to the 90's) ... Advice : delete this code and send a "diplomatic message" to the teacher.

Comment: Download customised version of Turbo C++ from Microsoft Codeplex for 32/64 bit OS including Windows 10 https://turboc.codeplex.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay,( they are teachers,, most of the time Ladies who always think they are in their 30s,when they used to work with turbo c, and don't to get over with it, huh,) Download and set up DOSBox, you can run TC through DOSBox.  http://www.dosbox.com

Edit: just realized that you asked more questions also : 
1 - Best place - Internet, Now the version you can get is around 3.5, most of the schools work with this version, no point in getting a newer version(even if it exists).

Comment: thanks for answer / i installed dos box / it seems every thing is ok about dos box for opening turbo c 3 / but turbo c has errors for runing it's samples such as circle.cpp / one of them is : can not open include file / i checked include directory in settings / but it's true